# Image view cannot find the image I put in the drawable res/folder

Tags: android, android-studio

Basically I downloaded 2 images and put them under the folder res/drawable and it appears in the left Project bar in android studio. But when I drag image view to the layout, it cannot find any of two I put inside the drawable folder.

Moreover, sometimes it can find, sometimes it can't.

Comment: Sync your project or restart the android studio it might help you.

Comment: Check when it is found, and when it isn't found

Comment: Go to File->Invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Check whether you see them in project view or Android view, because not everything is shown in the Android view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happened to me once. The images went to `drawable(v24)` folder and were not visible when creating an image view.

Obviously, first you have to check for synchronisation issues like said in the comments to the question. If that doesn't help, maybe this might work.

If your project window is in Android view, change it to project view(top left corner in the project window). Then move your images to `res/drawable` folder if they are in `res/drawable(v24)`.

Comment: Yes that's right, sync the IDE would work, finally it is resolved, thanks everyone.